# Where to copy wallpapers?

Tags: 2.2-froyo

I downloaded some wallpapers for my phone using the PC. Now, in which folder of my Android phone should I store them in order to be visible in Wallpaper Gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick solution : just copy them in DCIM (to use Gallery as a source) or store them in Picasa.

It'll allow you to get them from another handset if you want :)

EDIT (Thanks to Matt) : You can put the file in any folder of your FS, and Android will find it and suggest it as a wallpaper.

Comment: agreed, but want to add that you can store them in any folder and as long as they are picture files Android will allow you to choose them as wallpaper.  You don't need them to be in a "wallpaper" folder.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Works the same way as the music. I'll edit my answer .

Comment: I tried put in a folder wallpapers inside the SD but they are not retrieved by gallery. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Done! Using Media Rescan it update gallery with the new content added to SD, thank you.